# why the box is larger then the default under IE6?

Tags: html, css

the link is:   http://xanlz.com/test/one.html

the html:

```
<div class="cdright-toprab  rounded-corner">
<h2>Box one</h2>
   <div class="coderight-toprab">
  <ul class="item-list codeitem-list">
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
<li><a  href="#">example one</a><span>07-27</span></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

the style:

```
    .coderight-topr {
        width: 360px;
    }
    .cdright-toprab {
        border: 1px solid #8BD3EC;
        height: 286px;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 356px;
    }
    .coderight-toprab ul.codeitem-list {
        height: 253px;
       padding: 3px 0 0 7px;
    }
ul.item-list li{
  background: url("images/li_bg.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 8px transparent;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Why the `Box one` is  larger than the default width under IE6. how to correct it? thank you.

2,  why the `Box TWO` is  higher than the default height under IE6 and the content is not on the right of the `box two` text. how to correct it. thank you.

Comment: Because it's IE6.

Comment: i am sorry, the annoy thing is in my country. there are lots of users using IE6. anyone knows how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **`width`** property for `.coderight-topr H2` . You don't need the width and it's too wide.

Also a **side note**: the site is **not** properly coded.

Comment: thank you,you're right? do you know how to correct the second question. thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS hack to correct it:

```
.cdright-toprab {
    border: 1px solid #8BD3EC;
    height: 286px;
    _height: IE6 proper height;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 356px;
    _width: IE6 proper width;
}
```